# How to move multiple images in one activity in android

Tags: android, android-imageview, ontouchlistener

I have multiple image views in activity. I want to add touch,zoom in, zoom out, rotate image views. I am trying this but am getting only one image view will be move, rotate, zoom. other images does not touch. How can i do this. any one can tell me.

```
Main.class


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.images);


 image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
 image1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

 image.setOnTouchListener(new Touchhimage());
 image1.setOnTouchListener(new Touchhimage());

 }



 Touchhimage.class:


 public class Touchhimage implements OnTouchListener {  

 // These matrices will be used to move and zoom image  
public static Matrix matrix = new Matrix();  
public static Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();  

 // We can be in one of these 3 states  
 static final int NONE = 0;  
 static final int DRAG = 1;  
 static final int ZOOM = 2;  
 int mode = NONE;  

 // Remember some things for zooming  
 PointF start = new PointF();  
 PointF mid = new PointF();  
 float oldDist = 1f;  

 float[] lastEvent = null;
    float d = 0f;
    float newRot = 0f;  


    @Override  
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {  
  ImageView view = (ImageView) v;  
/*  double r = Math.atan2(event.getX() - view.getWidth() / 2, view.getHeight() / 2 - event.getY());
  int rotation = (int) Math.toDegrees(r);*/

  // Dump touch event to log  
  dumpEvent(event);  

  // Handle touch events here...  
  switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {  
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:  
   savedMatrix.set(matrix);  
   start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());  
   mode = DRAG;  
   break;  
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:  
   oldDist = spacing(event);  
   if (oldDist > 10f) {  
    savedMatrix.set(matrix);  
    midPoint(mid, event);  
    mode = ZOOM;  


   }  
   lastEvent = new float[4];
   lastEvent[0] = event.getX(0);
   lastEvent[1] = event.getX(1);
   lastEvent[2] = event.getY(0);
   lastEvent[3] = event.getY(1);
   d = rotation(event);

   break;  
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:  
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:  
      lastEvent = null;
   mode = NONE;  
   break;  
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:  

   if (mode == DRAG) {  
    // ...      
    matrix.set(savedMatrix);  
    matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y);      
   } else if (mode == ZOOM) {  
    float newDist = spacing(event);  
    if (newDist > 10f) {  
     matrix.set(savedMatrix);  
     float scale = newDist / oldDist;  
     matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);  
    }  
    if (lastEvent != null) {
        newRot = rotation(event);
        float r1 = newRot - d;
        matrix.postRotate(r1, view.getMeasuredWidth() / 2,
                view.getMeasuredHeight() / 2);
    }
   }  
   break;  
  }  

  view.setImageMatrix(matrix);  

 return true;

 // return false;


  // indicate event was handled  
 }  


 private float rotation(MotionEvent event) {
        double delta_x = (event.getX(0) - event.getX(1));
        double delta_y = (event.getY(0) - event.getY(1));
        double radians = Math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x);

        return (float) Math.toDegrees(radians);
    }

 /** Show an event in the LogCat view, for debugging */  
 @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event) {  
  String names[] = { "DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE",  
    "POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?" };  
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  
  int action = event.getAction();  
  int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;  
  sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);  
  if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN  
    || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {  
   sb.append("(pid ").append(  
     action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);  
   sb.append(")");  
  }  
  sb.append("[");  
  for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {  
   sb.append("#").append(i);  
   sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));  
   sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));  
   sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));  
   if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())  
    sb.append(";");  
  }  
  sb.append("]");  
 }  

 /** Determine the space between the first two fingers */  
 @SuppressLint("FloatMath") private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {  
  float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);  
  float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);  
  return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);  
 }  

 /** Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers */  
 private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {  
  float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);  
  float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);  
  point.set(x / 2, y / 2);  
 }  

 /**      rotation       **/
 float FindAngleDelta( float angle1, float angle2 )
 {
     float From = ClipAngleTo0_360( angle2 );
     float To   = ClipAngleTo0_360( angle1 );

     float Dist  = To - From;

     if ( Dist < -180.0f )
     {
         Dist += 360.0f;
     }
     else if ( Dist > 180.0f )
     {
         Dist -= 360.0f;
     }

     return Dist;
 }
 float ClipAngleTo0_360( float Angle )
 {
     float Res = Angle;
     while(Angle < 0) { Angle += 360.0; }
     while(Angle >= 360.0) { Angle -= 360.0; }
     return Res;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

because only one object can handle touch events at any given time, why not place an invisible view on top your entire screen and let it manage the touch events. it will need to know where other widgets are placed and move/rotate/zoom them accordingly to the user gesture

Comment: Thank you for your response but i can't understand.

Comment: relative layout lets you place views on top of each other. use relative layout as the viewgroup to place a custom view on top of your imageviews. the custom view will implement the onTouch method and decide according to the user gesture what to do.

Comment: am edited my question with code can u see once and tell me pls.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what your looking for. 
http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/multi.html

Also, try returning false in the OnTouch callback.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
         // Your code here
            return false;
        }
```

This will prevent the view from consuming the on touch event.

Comment: Thank you for your response am posting my code see once and tell me pls.